# Objective-C to Swift translation issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, translation, avcapturesession

I'm trying to translate this simple line of code to Swift, but can't figure out how to write it:

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
```

I've tried:

```
    let videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection = nil

    let videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection = false

    var videoConnection:AVCaptureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()
            videoConnection = nil

    var videoConnection:AVCaptureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()
            videoConnection = false

var videoConnection:AVCaptureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()
            videoConnection.active = false

var videoConnection:AVCaptureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()
            videoConnection.active = nil
```

Any suggestions on how to write this is Swift would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure, here you go: [Swift: The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309), [Swift: Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203), [AVCaptureConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureConnection/initWithInputPorts:output:)

Comment: What is it that that single line of code is doing? It's very likely that you don't need that line at all in Swift. Although you can do the same thing in Swift I question whether or not you actually need to in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to "initialize" something with nil it has to be an Optional.
So

```
var videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection? = nil
```

or

```
var videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection?
```

would be right.

Comment: Using `let` in either of these cases would leave you with a `nil` value that can never be changed.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't even makes sense :)

Comment: No worries, much better now :D

Comment: With Swift 1.2 the second case would work with let. :)

Comment: you wouldn't be able to use it until you initialize it. but you don't have to initialize it at the beginning, just before using.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be:

```
let videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection = UnsafePointer<Int8>.null()
```

Since Swift sort of conceals pointers from you (except that objects are really pointer references to the objects) and direct pointer manipulation, you sometimes have to contort yourself a bit. :)